# Why does mongdb or mongoose add quotes to a string query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a hardware database.  I want the `_id` for each piece fo hardware to be related to the number of items in the hardware collection.  Here is my schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var hardwareSchema = new Schema({
  manufacturer: {
    category: String
  },
  model: {
    type: String
  },
  _id : {
    type: String
  },
  category: {
    type: String
  }
});

var Hardware = mongoose.model('Hardware', hardwareSchema);

module.exports = Hardware;
```

I create the `_id` like so:

```
Hardware.find(function (err, hardwares) {
if (err) {
  throw err
}

var id = "" + (hardwares.length + 1000);

Hardware.findOne({_id:id}, function (err, hardware) {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }
  if (hardware) {
    createUnique(hardware);
  }
  else {
    console.log('okay to start a new item')

    var item = new Hardware({
      manufacturer: req.body.manufacturer,
      _id: id,
      model: req.body.model,
      category: req.body.category
    });

    item.save(function (err, item) {
     console.log('saved');
    }
```

This works very well.  However, when I try to retrieve the item by accessing it's `_id` property with a string later, it does not work.

For instance, if I use an `input` element, with the `type="text"` and use the input value as the id, I get no results. When logging the query, using something like this:

```
  Hardware.findOneAndIpdate({_id: checkout.itemCode}, {update: {updatedFiled:updatedItem}}, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
    if (!doc) {
      console.log('none');
    }
    console.log(doc)
  });
```

It just creates a new document.  Here is are pictures to show that the original schema does not have `"` around the `_id`, but my next one does.  Is there a way to remove these quotes?

Here you can see, the `itemCode` field, which I use in the query does not have quotes:

[image]

but then when I use it in the query, the quotes are added and a document is created (not updated)
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I'm totally following your question, but if you want the `_id` value stored as a number instead of a string, define it in your schema as `_id: Number` instead of defining it as a string as you are now.

Comment: Can you post an actual example of a `Hardware` document from the shell? Your question is confusing because your output from whatever GUI tool you're using doesn't match the schema.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your second _id is most likely a Number as Json parser probably parsed it to be a number for you. You probably want to make sure and convert this to a String.

So your second code would become:

```
Hardware.findOneAndUpdate({_id: checkout.itemCode + ""}, {update: {updatedFiled:updatedItem}}, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        throw err
    }
    if (!doc) {
        console.log('none');
    }
    console.log(doc)
});
```

If the above doesn't work, you can debug this by checking the type and making sure it's a String by doing console(typeof checkout.itemCode); and look at the type in the console. Hope this helps. You can do typeof check for both inputs just to make sure the type is the same. If they are not the same, findAndUpdate will create a new document as that's how mongo works.

Comment: They are all strings. You can see above the `types` of the variables.  Also, checking the types additional shows they are all strings. Unfortunately this code made no difference.

Comment: Can you also print out the content then, it's also likely that the first find  condition fails to find anything because checkout.itemCode is undefined and it's using updatedItem to update and updatedItem._id is a String?

Comment: Robomongo, from which I printed the above screen shots, shows the types. They are all strings.

Comment: I know in the db, it's all strings, can you print from the code. add some console.logs to check the type and what you have.